# Highcharts chart going blank on zoomType: 'x' area range zoom?

Tags: javascript, html, charts, highcharts

Ok, so I have a Highcharts chart displaying data correctly from a database; but the moment I zoom in, the chart goes blank?

Here is the chart HTML:

```
<div class="content" id="content"></div>
```

Here is the Javascript code for the chart:

```
$(function () {
        $('#content').highcharts({
            chart: {
                zoomType: 'x',
                backgroundColor:'transparent'
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Players Online'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: document.ontouchstart === undefined ?
                    'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in' :
                    'Drag your finger over the plot to zoom in'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                maxZoom: 3600000, // 1 hour
                title: {
                    text: null
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Players Online'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                enabled: false
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            plotOptions: {
                area: {
                    allowPointSelect: false,
                    fillColor: {
                        linearGradient: { x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1},
                        stops: [
                            [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                            [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                        ]
                    },
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    marker: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    shadow: false,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            lineWidth: 1,
                            enabled: false
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                type: 'area',
                data: [<?php echo join($data, ',') ?>]
                //This is displayed correctly in Javascript, so the issue isn't in my PHP
            }]
        });
    });
```

Am I doing something stupid here? Can't seem to find the cause of the chart going blank. :/

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231398/highcharts-not-displaying-data-at-some-zoom-levels

Comment: Have you sorted data by x ascending? Can you attach your Data object?

Comment: @SebastianBochan I linked the website where the chart is used so you can see the data in it live.

Comment: I opened your example and zoom via x works properly, which browsre do you use?

Comment: @SebastianBochan Ah, I actually found the solution to it myself after hunting through the Highcharts API documentation. I've added the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I worked out what the issue was after hunting through the Highcharts API documentation.

There is a property of all chart types that I'm aware of called 'cropThreshold', here is the link to the Highcharts API explaining what this is in detail:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.area.cropThreshold

But in summary; if you display more than 300 points (cropThreshold defaults to 300), then when zooming in, your chart will go blank. To correct this, you can add the following to your chart configuration:

```
area: {
           cropThreshold: 500 <- //Vary this. I display 500 points on my chart in
                                 //total and so a value of 500 allows zooming to
                                 //work at all levels. This will vary for you
                                 //depending on how many points you plot.
      }
```

Comment: I just saw in the API, they are telling that the points if overflow the cropthreshold will be cut down to the cropThreshold size which is 300 by default, then how can the chart can go blank...?

Comment: @user2634485 That's what I understood by the API too. But when I didn't have the cropThreshold set to above the number of points I had, the chart would go blank on zooming in. Maybe a bug with the particular configuration I had or an error on my part somewhere. I haven't experience this since, so I'm guessing it was a bug.