# Highcharts Bar Chart Zoom not working

Tags: highcharts, zooming, bar-chart

If you use a bar chart in Highcharts, the zoom does not seem to work properly.
You can select the area and also the button "Reset zoom" appears. The chart, however, is not zoomed in.

The only code I added to the basic bar example was the zoom type:

```
chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    zoomType: 'x'
},
```

Complete example: http://jsfiddle.net/966off9e/

Is this a bug or a feature? ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is somehow a bug in Highcharts, when you use `categorized` axis. But a workaround would be using a `min` for that axis:

```
xAxis: {
        categories: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'],
        title: {
            text: null
        },
        min: 0
}
```

Here's the [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/966off9e/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Just add 'minRange' to the xAxis: http://jsfiddle.net/mushigh/axy8v9oa/

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; max-width: 800px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar',
            zoomType: 'x'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Historic World Population by Region'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: Wikipedia.org'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'],
            title: {
                text: null
            },
            minRange: 1,
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Population (millions)',
                align: 'high'
            },
            labels: {
                overflow: 'justify'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' millions'
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: -40,
            y: 100,
            floating: true,
            borderWidth: 1,
            backgroundColor: ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColor) || '#FFFFFF'),
            shadow: true
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Year 1800',
            data: [107, 31, 635, 203, 2]
        }, {
            name: 'Year 1900',
            data: [133, 156, 947, 408, 6]
        }, {
            name: 'Year 2008',
            data: [973, 914, 4054, 732, 34]
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is that the amount of data is bigger than the cropThreshold variable. See [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864547/highcharts-chart-going-blank-on-zoomtype-x-area-range-zoom).

You can also see the [official docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.bar.cropThreshold) for this variable. Every kind of graphic has this variable with different default values. You should check it out to be sure.