# If over 300 values data disappears when zooming

Tags: highcharts

I am having a problem with a time series highchart where if the chart contains more than 300 values (starting at 301), if you zoom in, all data disappears. It doesn't matter where or how you zoom in, it always disappears. If the chart is configured exactly the same but with 300 or fewer values, this problem does not occur.

Here are 2 fiddles:

This works:
http://jsfiddle.net/briandemilia/LCYVv/18/

This does not work: (my problem)
http://jsfiddle.net/briandemilia/LCYVv/16/

(the only difference is the drop from 301 values to 300 values)

I thought this solution might work for me:
[Highcharts chart going blank on zoomType: 'x' area range zoom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17864547/highcharts-chart-going-blank-on-zoomtype-x-area-range-zoom)

But it does not solve the problem.

However the solution referenced there (quoted below) might provide some insight as I doubt it is a coincidence that this setting has a default of 300. I don't know what is different about my configuration to make this solution not work though.

```
area: {
       cropThreshold: 500 <- //Vary this. I display 500 points on my chart in
                             //total and so a value of 500 allows zooming to
                             //work at all levels. This will vary for you
                             //depending on how many points you plot.
  }
```

Comment: This is actually a bug - https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/4785

Answer (score 4):

Solution was to set this in the series not in plotoptions, like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/briandemilia/LCYVv/19/

```
        series: [

          { cropThreshold: 9999,
            name: 'Unique Employees',
            data: [ ......... ]
          .........
```